# mysql incorrect string value after changing encoding to utf8mb4

Tags: python, mysql, flask, utf-8, utf8mb4

i am trying to create a Flask application, and while creating the User mysql table i encountered a problem.

i am hashing the user's password using 32 bytes of salt, and 1000000 repeats of sha512 hashing attempts ( i am new to hashing, if this isn't the right way to do it, or isn't the right way to describe it, i would appreciate if you would correct me!).

while entering the user's info into the mysql database, i recieved the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value:  '\xFA\xBF\xBC\xEF\x85Y...' for column 'password_hashed'
```

i am logging into the database with charset of utf8mb4, and when i check the table properties in the mysql workbench, i can see that each table charset is utf8mb4.

i noticed that the length of the hashed password returns 288, so i increased the table char size from 128 to 300 just in case, but i dont see any reason it should be so long, as i read it should be 128 chars.

**code:**

user database model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    password_hashed = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)

def encrypt_password(self,password):
    salt = os.urandom(32)
    key = pbkdf2_hmac(
        'sha512',
        password.encode('utf-8'),
        salt,
        1000000
    )
    return salt+key

def verify_password(self,password):
    salt = self.password_hashed[0:32]
    hashed_password = self.password_hashed[32:]
    new_key = pbkdf2_hmac(
        'sha512',
        password.encode('utf-8'),
        salt,
        1000000
    )

    if new_key == hashed_password:
        return True
    return False
```

registration:

```
@app.route('/api/register',methods=['POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.json or not ('username' in request.json and 'password' in request.json):
            abort(400)

        user = User(username=request.json['username'],password_hashed=request.json['password'])
        user.password_hashed = user.encrypt_password(user.password_hashed)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=request.json['username']).first()
        return jsonify({'id': user.id, 'username': user.username})
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if new_key == hashed_password:` ... No no no that makes the `verify_password()` function prone to [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)..

Comment: Also a extra tip you also should prevent using the password column in the WHERE clause in short RDMS are nowadays designed to deliver stabile times when (fully) scanning/using the table or index.. So you need to use `SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?` and `verify_password(posted_user_password, row['password'])` (pseudo code) assuming that function to be safe..

Comment: `pbkdf2_hmac` should only return a string with chars with in the `0-9 a-z (A-Z)` ranges... right ?  So why did you use utf8 in the first place charsets like ascii or latin1 would be much better as using utf8 or utf8mb4 is pretty much  *"overkill"* in terms off storage and performance for this data range as utf8 and utf8mb4 using more complex encoding rules then what latin1 or ascii uses..

Comment: Multiple calls to a hashing function is no better than one call.

Comment: For securely comparing password hashes, use the [compare_digest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.compare_digest) function exported by the `secrets` and `hmac` libraries in the standard library.